# Can "using" fully replace "typedef" in all cases?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, typedef, using

I know `using` can do something `typedef` cannot do.

I just wonder whether `using` can fully replace `typedef` in all cases?

Comment: @juanchopanza: example?

Comment: @juanchopanza: You misunderstood the question if that is the example. The question is "can `using` replace `typedef`?" **not** "can `typedef` replace `using`?".

Comment: Yes, `using` can replace `typedef` in all cases.

Comment: @Nawaz you are right, I got it the wrong way around. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it can, quote from the [draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf) (bold emphasis mine)

**7.1.3 The typedef speciﬁer [dcl.typedef]**

> 2 A typedef-name can also be introduced by an alias-declaration. The
>   identiﬁer following the using keyword becomes a typedef-name and the
>   optional attribute-speciﬁer-seq following the identiﬁer appertains to
>   that typedef-name. **It has the same semantics as if it were introduced
>   by the typedef speciﬁer.**

Comment: +1. However, if so, why did the committee not overload the semantics of typedef instead of overload that of using?

Comment: @Angew you are right, withdrawn. In any case, the motivation for a new keyword should be somewhere in the original draft proposals.

Comment: The rationale can be found in n1489.pdf‎: `However, it also displays several disavantages among which the confusion of using a keyword known to introduce an alias for a type-name in a context where the alias does not designate a type, but a template; Vec is not an alias for a type, and should not be taken for a typedef-name. The name Vec is a name for the family std::vector<T,MyAllocator<T> >.
Consequently we do not propose the typedef syntax.`

Comment: @JesseGood tnx, that's the right quote. The template alias adds 2 features: template generalization and left-to-right. To add either to `typedef` would be confusing.

Comment: Your initial statement may be correct, but your quote doesn't prove it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Well strictly speaking, you might be right, but the quote IMO provides a translation "algorithm". Can you give a counterexample where that wouldn't work?